# How to debug my dynamodb insert not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am not able to insert an item in my dynamodb table.

My code is the following:

```
   function insert() {
        const item = {
            itemId: 'itemId',
            name: 'itemName',
            status: 'itemStatus'
        };

        const params = {
            TableName: 'sls-basic-operations-items-dev',
            Item: item
        };

        console.log('ready to insert', params);

        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

        docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return false;
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
        const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
        console.log('new event to be consumed', message);

        await insert();
}
```

the lambda log entries are not very detailed either.

all i see is:

```
START RequestId: b71ea056-85f0-424d-ad55-4b4571aeeccf Version: $LATEST
2019-06-14T23:13:13.012Z    b71ea056-85f0-424d-ad55-4b4571aeeccf    new event to be consumed
{
    "description": "test item"
}

    2019-06-14T23:13:13.032Z    b71ea056-85f0-424d-ad55-4b4571aeeccf    ready to insert { TableName: 'sls-basic-operations-items-dev',
    Item: { itemId: 'itemId', name: 'itemName', status: 'itemStatus' } }
    END RequestId: b71ea056-85f0-424d-ad55-4b4571aeeccf
    REPORT RequestId: b71ea056-85f0-424d-ad55-4b4571aeeccf  Duration: 119.28 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 76 MB
```

nothing more and no entries in the table...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `insert()` function is implemented as a synchronous function call (it returns `undefined` immediately when `docClient.put()` is invoked), despite the intent of being asynchronous.

Try to change the last lines of the `insert()` function to return a promise:

```
 return docClient.put(params).promise();
```

Then you can wrap the call to `insert()` in a `try` / `catch`:

```
 try {
    const data = await insert();
    console.log('success', data);
 } catch (err) {
    console.log('failure', err);
    throw err;
 }:
```

More info about usage of `Promise` and `async` / `await` in Lambda functions can be found in the [Node.js 8.10 runtime now available in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/)